# GitHub Sync Fork From Windows Client

Tags: git, github

I can merge my branch or sync from the upstream by using the shell but, is there any easier way to accomplish this without using the shell?

I have been [following this instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork)  but is there any easier solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Atlassian SourceTree is a free graphical GIT Client for Windows & Mac: http://sourcetreeapp.com/

Also there is GitHub Windows, which also avoids having to enter shell commands: http://windows.github.com/

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The User asked for an easy way to use GIT without the Shell under Windows and this is a good graphical GIT client.